# Loop through the lines of a text file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, loops, visual-studio-2008, text

I have a text file with some lines of text in it.

I want to loop through each line until an item that I want is found*, then display it on the screen, in the form of a label.

*I am searching for the item through a textbox.

That is, in sudo:

```
For i = 0 To number of lines in text file
    If txtsearch.text = row(i).text Then
        lbl1.text = row(i).text
Next i
```

Comment: Could there be more than one occurrence? Once it's found what do you want, the word or the whole line? Please give more details....

Comment: Sorry, after re-reading it, it did sound a bit vague, I want all the text on that line. There wont be more than one occurrence of a line.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your UI? Example of your input file? Example of program output?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [File.ReadLines Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to iterate throughout your file, one line at a time. Here is a simple example:

```
    Dim Term As String = "Your term"
    For Each Line As String In File.ReadLines("Your file path")
        If Line.Contains(Term) = True Then
            ' Do something...Print the line
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: One line at a time would be ReadLines, RealAllLines is to read all lines at once.

Comment: @Neolisk Actually, they both work. ReadAllLines will indeed read all the line at once, but we can still iterate through them one line at a time. Please provide additional information about your downvote reasons.

Comment: @Eminem: I usually either downvote or leave a comment. My reasoning is that downvoting does not help the person improve. But sometimes I just cannot find words, or the person is so stubborn and/or arrogant, so this is time to downvote. You said to use ReadAllLines to iterate one line at a time. Because iteration does not assume streamed processing, there is confusion. Your post may be misinterpreted by the reader. StackOverflow is often treated as a "source of truth". Now because **stream** is sort of **one line at a time** (even through the opposite is not true), the truth is skewed.

Comment: @Neolisk Readlines is only needed when read, on the other hand ReadAllLines are put into an array before they can be iterated over and checked. So as it stands, his answer is good and more sufficient. On another note to my answer, File.ReadLines is a bit slower than the raw StreamReader, but not significantly slower. This is the expected result since File.ReadLines simply makes an ReadLinesIterator internally which uses a StreamReader and does some extra checking along the way. Here's some benchmarking tests to confirm these http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-read-text-files

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR: Bottom line, OP could use streams, based on their requirement. The above answer does not recommend streams. Hence, no upvote from me. No downvote either, because it's not wrong, just inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that will spit back your string from the row that contains your search term...

```
  Public Shared Function SearchFile(ByVal strFilePath As String, ByVal strSearchTerm As String) As String
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(strFilePath)
    Dim strLine As String = String.Empty

    Try
        Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
            strLine = String.Empty
            strLine = sr.ReadLine
            If strLine.Contains(strSearchTerm) Then
                sr.Close()
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        Return strLine
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return String.Empty
    End Try
  End Function
```

To use the function you can do this...

```
 Dim strText As String = SearchFile(FileName, SearchTerm)
 If strText <> String.Empty Then
   Label1.Text = strText
 End If
```

Comment: To be consistent with my suggestions on the other answer, I upvoted your answer, because it recommends streams - to keep it simple.

Comment: I am trying to use this solution for something very similar, but to find an integer value (and ONLY an integer value) amongst multiple rows of CSV, each row containing two doubles and one integer. I changed the second function parameter to "ByVal intSearchNum As Integer", but it is still returning a true even when it detects the passed-in integer value as part of one of the doubles. So a row containing a double value of 6.67 comes back as a match to an integer value of 67, which I DON'T want.

Answer (score 0):

LOOPING AND GETTING ALL XML FILES FROM DIRECTORY IF WE WANT TEXTFILES PUT "*.txt" IN THE PLACE OF "*xml"

Dim Directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(Path)

```
    Dim allFiles As IO.FileInfo() = Directory.GetFiles("*.xml")
    allFiles = allFiles.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.FullName).ToArray()
    Dim singleFile As IO.FileInfo


    For Each singleFile In allFiles
        'ds.ReadXml(singleFile)
        xd.Load(singleFile.FullName)

        Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = xd.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/ORDER/ORDER_HEADER")
        Dim ORDER_NO As String = " "
        For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
            If Not node.SelectSingleNode("ORDER_NO") Is Nothing Then
                ORDER_NO = node.SelectSingleNode("ORDER_NO").InnerText
            End If
        Next

    Next
```