# Loop through contents in the text file

Tags: vb.net

New TechGuy on this site. Thought i'd make this resourceful since im getting ready to graduate and want more programming practice. I have a question:

I tried looping through a text file I created and I wanted to replace each multiple of 3 with the word "changed". I created a text file and entered numbers 1-15 on each line. My code is below but for some reason it would only change the number 3 and 13. I tried using this link as a resource ([Loop through the lines of a text file in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731772/vb-net-loop-through-lines-of-a-text-file)) but that wasnt to helpful. Anyway here is my code, can someone help with what i'm doing wrong?

```
Public Class numbers

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    Dim OpenFilePrompt As New OpenFileDialog
    openFilePrompt.ShowDialog()
    Dim currentReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(OpenFilePrompt.FileName)
    txtInput.Text = currentReader.ReadToEnd

    Dim a As String

    Dim numbers As New List(Of String)

    a = txtInput.Text
    numbers.Add(a)

    Dim b As Integer

    For i = 0 To numbers.Count Step 3
        b = b + 3

        TextBox2.Text = (numbers.Item(i).Replace(b.ToString, "Changed"))

    Next


  End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of what your text file looks like?

Comment: 1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15 (the numbers are vertical not horizontal like it appears on here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `numbers` (the first item) to `a`, which is `txtInput.Text`.
Then you have a one size list which is completely useless!

You should use [`Mod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx) instead.

> Divides two numbers and returns only the remainder.

So just check if `Integer Mod 3` equals `0`.

Also consider using [`File.ReadAllLines(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`Val(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), [`String.Join(String, String())`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`File.WriteAllLines(String, String())`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Dim Content() As String = File.ReadAllLines(OpenFilePrompt.FileName)
For Index As Integer = 0 To Content.Length - 1
    Dim Number As Integer = Val(Content(Index))
    If Number Mod 3 = 0 Then
        Content(Index) = "changed"
    End If
Next
txtInput.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, Content)
File.WriteAllLines(OpenFilePrompt.FileName, Content)
```

Comment: Hey joiner, thanks! That works perfectly! I figured that each line break would add a new string to the list... Dim numbers as New List (Of STring) = currentReader.ReadToEnd thinking it would add each number to the list. BUt your solution worked.

Comment: @TechGuyChris No, you were setting the first item of the list to the entire file.