# Automatically adding an incrementing number when reading text file on specific line

Tags: vb.net

I need to be able to automatically add a number to a specific line when I'm reading a text file
Let's say I save 5 lines (1question and 4choices of answer)
I need my program to automatically add Question# "1-2-3-4-5 Everytime it gets on the question line in the text box. 
So it would look like that

Question #1<---- what I need

Ans:a

Ans:b

Ans:c

Ans:D

Question #2 <-----what I need

Comment: ...and the age-old refrain: *what have you tried?*  We are not here to do your homework for you.  Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour] <------ what we need

Comment: When you reach a line that starts with the word "Question", you increment your counter variable.

Comment: Problem is I'm not sure how to make my loop and what element to pass through it. I'd need an example to understand it

Comment: Example [provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25732216/6144259)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are the basics of what you are after.
This first example goes on the presumption that you will add a question number to each line that starts with the word "question"

```
Imports System.IO
    Sub Main()

        Dim sourceFile As String
        Dim newFile As String
        Dim tracker As Integer = 0


        sourceFile = "C:\\temp\\43494_1.txt"
        newFile = "C:\\temp\\43494_1_new.txt"


        Using sw As New StreamWriter(newFile) 'write the new file
            Using sr As New StreamReader(sourceFile) 'read the source file
                Dim currentLine As String = String.Empty
                While (sr.Peek >= 0) 'while there is something to read
                    currentLine = sr.ReadLine()
                    If currentLine.ToLower.StartsWith("question") Then
                        tracker = tracker + 1 'increment the question tracker
                        sw.WriteLine(currentLine & tracker)
                    Else
                        sw.WriteLine(currentLine)
                    End If

                End While
            End Using
        End Using

    End Sub
```

This second example goes on the presumption that for every question, there is always 4 answers, which means that each question is really a block of 5 lines, and the snippet assumes that line 1 of your source file is the first question.

```
    Imports System.IO
    Sub Main()
        Dim sourceFile As String
        Dim newFile As String
        sourceFile = "C:\\temp\\43494_1.txt"
        newFile = "C:\\temp\\43494_1_new.txt"

        Dim lineTracker As Integer = 0
        Dim questionTracker As Integer = 0

        Using sw As New StreamWriter(newFile) 'write the new file
            Using sr As New StreamReader(sourceFile) 'read the source file
                Dim currentLine As String = String.Empty
                While (sr.Peek >= 0) 'while there is something to read
                    currentLine = sr.ReadLine()

                    'reset the lineTracker if you need to
                    If lineTracker = 5 Then
                        lineTracker = 0
                    End If

                    lineTracker = lineTracker + 1 'increment the lineTracker

                    If lineTracker = 1 Then
                        questionTracker = questionTracker + 1 'increment the question tracker
                        sw.WriteLine(currentLine & questionTracker)
                    Else
                        sw.WriteLine(currentLine)
                    End If
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! that did the trick. I would never have found it myself. Im very new at this.